# CSS: Alignment of items within a div

Tags: css

Getting started with CSS and wordpress. I have a bit of a programming background but am relatively new to web design.

I'm trying to make a child theme in wordpress, and I'd like to do something simple like edit the "title element so it is centred and beside the logo. Right now it puts it below the logo within a custom-header div.

I can move it by adjusting the padding or using relative positioning but it feels wrong to be using absolute values. I want to be able to say "put it at half the height of the last element and beside it". I don't exactly understand how to say that in code, much less how to do that by just overriding the style.css file rather than tracing down exactly where its defined.

Comment: Could you share the CSS and HTML of the items in question?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the shared [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avijitkr/654yfz86/)

```css
.a {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.a img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.a p {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 30px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="a">
            <img src="http://php.quicoto.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/css3.jpg" height="100" width="133">
            <p> Title of the page </p>
        </div>
```

link.
I have coded an html based on your query.

Is this what you require?